# Cómo puedo maximizar el uso de la sección title en un ListTile en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-layout

Como puedo eliminar el gap entre el title y el trailing de un ListTile, para usar la parte derecha del title del ListTile que va antes que el trailing, maximizando así el área dedicada al texto del title?  Intenté manipulando los valores de minLeadingWidth y el horizontalTitleGap, pero eso no parece hacer llegar el texto a la parte que necesito, marcada abajo en rojo, ni aún alineándolo a la derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mostrá un [repro] del código que tenés hasta el momento: leé [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Lo mejor sería crear tu propio widget con `Row` y `Column`, así tienes control de lo que quieres mostrar exactamente.

Revisé el código del `ListTile` y viene con tamaños definidos para cada porción, pero veo que hay una propiedad interesante.

```dart
 final double adjustedTrailingWidth = hasTrailing
        ? math.max(trailingSize.width + _effectiveHorizontalTitleGap, 32.0)
        : 0.0;
```

Intenta con el `horizontalTitleGap` del `ListTile`, por default es 16, intenta con 0.

```dart
ListTile(
   horizontalTitleGap: 0,
 );
```

Reference:

```
  /// The horizontal gap between the titles and the leading/trailing widgets.
  ///
  /// If null, then the value of [ListTileTheme.horizontalTitleGap] is used. If
  /// that is also null, then a default value of 16 is used.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de evaluar mi pregunta.  El horizontalTitleGap es el espacio a la izquierda del texto, entre el texto y el ícono del leading, el cual de hecho ya estaba puesto en cero al momento de la foto del ListTile.  Coincido en que uno terminaría armando el widget de cero para saltear el problema.  Es una lástima que no haya una solución fácil para usar esa parte del Widget ya armado.

Comment: ya veo, que extraño que la descripción diga:  The horizontal gap between the titles and the leading/trailing widgets  ,  leading/trailing <-